# Very low volume audio through Bluetooth since networking restart

Tags: pulseaudio, bluez

I'm running Debian 8, and I've been successfully using Pulseaudio/BlueZ to play audio through a Bluetooth speaker.

Today I restarted my networking stack in order to try and fix a WiFi problem, and since then the audio has been very, very quiet. I usually have the speaker on very low volume, but now I can't hear anything unless it's on full - and even then it's quiet.

The speaker is fine with other inputs.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Here is the sink from pacmd list-sinks:

```
index: 2
name: <bluez_sink.40_EF_4C_87_A6_85>
driver: <module-bluez5-device.c>
flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME 
state: RUNNING
suspend cause: 
priority: 9030
volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
volume steps: 65537
muted: no
current latency: 32.82 ms
max request: 3 KiB
max rewind: 0 KiB
monitor source: 3
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
used by: 1
linked by: 1
fixed latency: 45.32 ms
card: 2 <bluez_card.40_EF_4C_87_A6_85>
module: 27
properties:
    bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp_sink"
    device.description = "AXiS X3"
    device.string = "40:EF:4C:87:A6:85"
    device.api = "bluez"
    device.class = "sound"
    device.bus = "bluetooth"
    device.form_factor = "headset"
    bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_40_EF_4C_87_A6_85"
    bluez.class = "0x240404"
    bluez.alias = "AXiS X3"
    device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
    device.intended_roles = "phone"
ports:
    headset-output: Headset (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        properties:

active port: <headset-output>
```

And here is the only sink input:

```
1 sink input(s) available.
index: 1
driver: <protocol-native.c>
flags: START_CORKED 
state: RUNNING
sink: 2 <bluez_sink.40_EF_4C_87_A6_85>
volume: front-left: 65535 / 100% / -0.00 dB,   front-right: 65535 / 100% / -0.00 dB
        balance 0.00
muted: no
current latency: 982.00 ms
requested latency: 45.32 ms
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
resample method: (null)
module: 11
client: 16 <Spotify>
properties:
    media.role = "music"
    media.name = "Spotify"
    application.name = "Spotify"
    native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
    native-protocol.version = "29"
    application.process.id = "1555"
    application.process.user = "richard"
    application.process.host = "debian"
    application.process.binary = "spotify"
    window.x11.display = ":0.0"
    application.language = "en_GB.utf8"
    application.process.machine_id = "1b66e5d6e5fc45b981704645611058d0"
    application.process.session_id = "1"
    application.icon_name = "spotify-client"
    module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:music"
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Did you find any solution? I am facing the exact same problem. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @nolazybits, unfortunately I didn't! I had to resort to a cable, and now I'm on OS X. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but noticed that every time I connected to the headphones the maximum volume available would be different. e.g. 100% on the laptop could be either quiet or loud with the same test audio.

Also it didn't matter whether it was headphones or a portable BT speaker. Same issue.

I use my bluetooth headset with both my android phone and my Pop!OS system. Pop!OS uses pulseaudio like Ubuntu. So, I'm often disconnecting from one device and connecting to another.

**Here's how I solved it:**

1. Connect the headphones to my android phone.
2. Start some audio playing over the headphones.
3. Increase the volume to maximum using the buttons on the headphones, or via the phone if the speaker doesn't have volume buttons.
4. Disconnect the headphones from the phone.
5. Connect the headphones to the computer.

**Now the maximum perceived volume via the OS is the same as for the phone.**

It seems that the bluetooth functionality on the computer is not able to correctly read the current volume setting on the speakers device, or may use a different scaling factor. The, on connection, it makes some assumption about the volume state on the speakers that is not correct.

This is all anecdotal at this point, but I will post this elsewhere because there are a lot of people stating a similar problem.